# SQL Alias Column Name Needed In CASE WHEN Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

How can I reference the alias "New Date?" I keep getting an "Invalid column name 'NewDate'" error.

```
CASE
    WHEN p.Program IN ('program1') THEN (date_needed + 10)
    WHEN p.Program IN ('program2') THEN (date_needed + 20)
END AS [NewDate]

CASE 
    WHEN date_needed < [NewDate] THEN 'Program On Time' 
    ELSE 'Program Late'
END AS [Modified New Date]
```

Comment: Scope issue. You need a sub-query.

Comment: If you don't want to subquery, perhaps for performance reasons, you could also inline the first `CASE` expression, replacing the `[NewDate]` marker in second `CASE` expression.

Comment: Be very careful here. You are using basic addition syntax for adding days to a date. This doesn't always work. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the `CASE`

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN CASE
           WHEN p.Program IN ('program1') THEN (date_needed + 10)
           WHEN p.Program IN ('program2') THEN (date_needed + 20)
         END < [NewDate] THEN 'Program On Time' 
    ELSE 'Program Late'
END AS [Modified New Date]
```

Or use a sub-query, or CTE...

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN p.Program IN ('program1') THEN (date_needed + 10)
    WHEN p.Program IN ('program2') THEN (date_needed + 20)
END AS [NewDate], date_needed
FROM YourTable)

SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN date_needed < [NewDate] THEN 'Program On Time' 
    ELSE 'Program Late'
END AS [Modified New Date]
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of logical query processing order, it is not possible to reference `NewDate` column in same block. To achieve this you can use common table expression as follows:

```
WITH Base_CTE
AS
(
SELECT CASE
    WHEN p.Program IN ('program1') THEN (date_needed + 10)
    WHEN p.Program IN ('program2') THEN (date_needed + 20)
END AS [NewDate], date_nedded
FROM tablename
)
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN date_needed < [NewDate] THEN 'Program On Time' 
    ELSE 'Program Late'
END AS [Modified New Date]
FROM Base_CTE;
```

Comment: Totally unrelated: I saw that your flagged for "editing" on the triage queue for https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20799771 ... simply: wrong decision. This question requires the OP to remove the screen shots, and to put the corresponding text into the question as text. Only the OP should do such things. So please keep in mind: only triage for editing when *other* people can edit the question. Anything that requires the *owner* to improve the content, should not go "edit".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @GhostCat

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for the re-feedback. And just in case you are wondering: I noticed that because I am currently working on the "Help and improve" queue. The one that gets fed the "edit" triages. And finding such content there is simply a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` or `subquery`  :

```
select p.*, (case when p.date_needed < p1.NewDate 
                  then 'Program On Time' 
                  else 'Program Late' 
              end) as [Modified New Date]
from table p cross apply
     ( values (  case when p.Program = 'program1' 
                      then (date_needed + 10)
                      when p.Program = 'program2' 
                      then (date_needed + 20)
                  end
              )
     ) p1(NewDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of `apply` for this purpose:

```
SELECT v.date_needed,
       (CASE WHEN v.date_needed < [NewDate] THEN 'Program On Time' 
             ELSE 'Program Late'
        END) AS [Modified New Date]
FROM t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN t.Program IN ('program1') THEN (date_needed + 10)
                   WHEN t.Program IN ('program2') THEN (date_needed + 20)
              END)
     ) v(date_needed)
```